# How can I stop the Scroll bar from moving? html/css

Tags: html, css, animation, rotation, transform

How can I make the scroll bar stop? You can see the scroll bar which is on the left. I think there is not any problem with the HTML code but I'm sure there is a problem with the CSS code.

I first thought that it was a problem with the margin or length, but it wasn't.

Here is my CSS & HTML code, How can I fix it? or Where is the problem? -

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color:  black;
}
.trans_box {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: green;
    
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;

    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    animation: block-rotate 6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes block-rotate {
    0% {transform: rotate(0);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.part {
    position: absolute;
    width:180px;
    height:180px;

    -webkit-border-radius:200px 0 0 0; 
    -moz-border-radius:200px 0 0 0;
}

#one {
    background-color:blue; 
    top: -70%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    
}
#two {
    background-color: pink; 
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    left: 70%;
}
#three {
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    left: -70%;
}
#four {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    top: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainpage.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="trans_box">
            <div class="part" id="one"></div>
            <div class="part" id="two"></div>
            <div class="part" id="three"></div>
            <div class="part" id="four"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

add body {overflow: hidden;} into your CSS, fixed code is here:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color:  black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.trans_box {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: green;
    
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;

    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    animation: block-rotate 6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes block-rotate {
    0% {transform: rotate(0);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.part {
    position: absolute;
    width:180px;
    height:180px;

    -webkit-border-radius:200px 0 0 0; 
    -moz-border-radius:200px 0 0 0;
}

#one {
    background-color:blue; 
    top: -70%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    
}
#two {
    background-color: pink; 
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    left: 70%;
}
#three {
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    left: -70%;
}
#four {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    top: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainpage.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="trans_box">
            <div class="part" id="one"></div>
            <div class="part" id="two"></div>
            <div class="part" id="three"></div>
            <div class="part" id="four"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. I finally fixed the problem thanks to you.

Comment: @kimking Thank you too. :) You're welcome to accept the answer so that people from the future with the same issue can solve their problem faster.